# Exclude Duplicates in Tableau Server Custom SQL (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2, tableau-api

I need to create a flag to let executives understand system usage. We have 3 major systems that people work in, and we're trying to transition users off of one of them. My query does this, but the nature of the table that I'm querying includes duplicates because the CREATE_USER_CD field is not distinct. It repeats (per FROM_ID) for each event type associated with an order.

I've tried adding this as a condition to only include the last user to trigger the event TYPE_ID that I am looking for:

```
    and e.MISC_EVENT_ID in (select max(MISC_EVENT_ID) 

    from VASDW.MISC_EVENT 

    where date(CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01 and current date

    group by FROM_ID)
```

This is the main thrust of the script:

```
select e.CREATE_TS, e.MISC_EVENT_ID, e.CREATE_USER_CD, e.FROM_ID,

(case when upper(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> e.CREATE_USER_CD

and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'jboss' 

and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'MTier'

and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'wlsedi' 

and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'svrcflp' then 1 else 0 end) 

as CLG_FG

from VASDW.MISC_EVENT e

where date(e.CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01' and current date
```

I am expecting to get the MISC_EVENT_ID of the last user who created the event type that I'm looking for when I add the above condition. However, I'm getting duplicates.

```
CREATE_TS          MISC_EVENT_ID CREATE_USER_CD FROM_ID  CLG_FG
2019-03-20 14:00    1236064301    Sego, Jona    15293831     1
2019-03-21 10:48    1236092481    Barnes, Ja    15293831     1
```

Any ideas besides writing this as a CTE to help? I can't write a CTE because I'm using this custom SQL as part of a larger Tableau Server workbook. My counts are correct because I'm using countd() within Tableau, but the duplicates show up when you do an extract. Someone will question this before long so I'm trying to avoid it altogether.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your code example. You don't include the same `case` expression in the `where` clause of your subselect with `group by`.
Run it as is.
Do you get the expected result (2-nd row only) on the following data?

```
with "VASDW.MISC_EVENT" 
(CREATE_TS, MISC_EVENT_ID, CREATE_USER_CD, FROM_ID, TYPE_ID, FROM_CLASS_ID) as (values
  (timestamp('2019-03-20-14.00.00'), 1236064301, 'Sego, Jona', 15293831, 1852, 32)
, (timestamp('2019-03-21-10.48.00'), 1236092481, 'Barnes, Ja', 15293831, 1852, 32)
, (timestamp('2019-03-20-14.00.00'), 2236064301, 'Sego, Jona', 15293832, 1852, 32)
, (timestamp('2019-03-21-10.48.00'), 2236092481, 'BARNES, JA', 15293832, 1852, 32)
)
select e.FROM_ID, e.CREATE_USER_CD, e.MISC_EVENT_ID,
(case when upper(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> e.CREATE_USER_CD
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'jboss' 
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'MTier'
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'wlsedi' 
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'svrcflp' then 1 else 0 end) as CLG_FG
from "VASDW.MISC_EVENT" e
    where date(e.CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01' and current date
    and e.TYPE_ID = 1852
    and e.FROM_CLASS_ID = 32 
    and (case when upper(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> e.CREATE_USER_CD
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'jboss' 
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'MTier'
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'wlsedi' 
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'svrcflp' then 1 else 0 end = 1)
    and e.MISC_EVENT_ID in (
        select max(e2.MISC_EVENT_ID) 
        from "VASDW.MISC_EVENT" e2 
            where e2.TYPE_ID = 1852
            and e2.FROM_CLASS_ID = 32
            and date(e2.CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01' and current date
    group by e2.FROM_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, but this is custom SQL for Tableau Server, so CTE isn't an option. For a little more background, FROM_ID is basically an order number, and each name and timestamp is tied to an event TYPE_ID. I have to look for a specific TYPE_ID and the person and time stamp associated with it, but that event TYPE_ID can be duplicated - even by user and FROM_ID so it gets messy. MISC_EVENT_ID is the only non-duplicating field available, which is why I assumed that getting the max(MISC_EVENT_ID) that is associated with FROM_ID would do the trick.

Comment: My example uses CTE to provide you a complete solution with test data generated on the fly. You don’t need it in your case. There is nothing about TYPE_ID in your example. Can you provide your test data in a table form and the result needed? It’s hard to understand what you need from such an explanation as above...

Comment: I am terrible at formatting here, sorry. I need a certain TYPE_ID from the table so that I'm filtering out all other event types that don't apply to this CLG_FG alias. MISC_EVENT_ID is the PK for this table, so my thought was that I'd find the max(MISC_EVENT_ID) for each FROM_ID that meets my TYPE_ID conditions. But I am still getting duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for getting me pointed back in the right direction by pointing out the info that I didn't provide in my original post, Mark. The solution came to me as I was typing my reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
e.MISC_EVENT_ID = (select max(me2.MISC_EVENT_ID) 

                   from VASDW.MISC_EVENT me2
                   where me2.FROM_ID = me.FROM_ID and

                         me2.CREATE_TS >= '2019-01-01 and
                         me2.CREATE_TS < add_days(current date, 1)
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried a self join earlier and it didn't work, but the subquery will likely solve this problem. I'll give that a shot an report back. I've been banging my head against the wall on this since this afternoon, though. So might not be until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.FROM_ID, e.CREATE_USER_CD, e.MISC_EVENT_ID,
(case when upper(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> e.CREATE_USER_CD
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'jboss' 
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'MTier'
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'wlsedi' 
    and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'svrcflp' then 1 else 0 end) as CLG_FG
from VASDW.MISC_EVENT e
    where date(e.CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01' and current date
    and e.TYPE_ID = 1852
    and e.FROM_CLASS_ID = 32 
    and (case when upper(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> e.CREATE_USER_CD
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'jboss' 
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'MTier'
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'wlsedi' 
        and trim(e.CREATE_USER_CD) <> 'svrcflp' then 1 else 0 end = 1)
    and e.MISC_EVENT_ID in (
        select max(e2.MISC_EVENT_ID) 
        from VASDW.MISC_EVENT e2 
            where e2.TYPE_ID = 1852
            and e2.FROM_CLASS_ID = 32
            and date(e2.CREATE_TS) between '2019-01-01' and current date
    group by e2.FROM_ID)
```

I guess it wasn't working because I didn't include my filters for TYPE_ID AND FROM_CLASS_ID in the subquery. I took the "don't post the entire code" tip too literally. Sorry for not providing enough info for those who tried to answer. It works now though. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Look at my updated answer with a question on the result.

Comment: I ran this without adding the case filters to my subquery, and only row 2 was returned, which would be expected since the max(MISC_EVENT_ID) associated with FROM_ID 15293832 has a CREATE_USER_CD that doesn't meet my criteria for the flag. Same results if I add the filters from my case statement. Is that how it should work?

Comment: Also, it never occurred to me to create a CTE to test queries, so thanks.

Comment: A little background on the business logic: I need to flag from which systems users are tendering orders. We aren't backing up data from our new Carrier Lead Generation (CLG) system yet though, so the developers handed off ( case when CREATE_USER_CD  like '%,%') - 'FirstName, LastName' - as the flag to use. That doesn't account for longer names though, so it's not robust enough for reporting. You could also see a server name 'jboss' or a name like JSEGO, which are from different sources. So I needed to create something on the fly on Friday. Thus what I posted.

Comment: So any user who tendered an order from this CLG system will show up as 'LastName, FirstName' in this events table. They will always be letter case. I just needed a flag that was agnostic to the length of someone's last name because our VASDW.MISC_EVENT table stores CREATE_USER_CD as char(10). So in the case of a last name like 'Greensleeves', it's stored as 'Greensleev' in the CREATE_USER_CD field and cannot meet the '%,%' criteria even though I can look at it and know that it's from CLG.

Comment: And this will all be moot in 2 - 3 weeks when our ETL group finishes up the process of creating tables for CLG in our warehouse...